# jQuery calculation gives NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to do a calculation, but i constantly get the error NaN;
Could you help me out how to do the math for var testBottom?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var test = jQuery("#test");
var testTopOffset = test.offset();
var testTop = testTopOffset;
var testHeight = test.height();
var testBottom = parseInt(testTop + testHeight);
alert(testHeight);
alert(testBottom);
});
```

Comment: try parseInt(testTop) + parseInt(testHeight);

Comment: what value is getting on testTop  & testHeight ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test.offset();` returns an object with `top` and `left` properties, not a number. if you want the top offset you need to drill down:

```
var testTopOffset = test.offset().top;
```

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

Answer (score 1):

```
var testTopOffset = test.offset();
```

should be

```
var testTopOffset = test.offset().top
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too, same as jbabey!